# How to formulate pylint rule to allow private variable starting with `__`

Tags: python, oop, pylint, information-hiding

Basically I have a class with a private variable:

```py
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, abAb):
      self.__abAb = abAb
```

Now, pylint complains:

```
Attribute name "__abAb" doesn't conform to camelCase naming style
```

Python does not really know about private variables, but as far as I know, it can be achieved by prepending two underscores. However, now I have the problem, that pylint complains and I did not yet find an elegant way to disable that message, whereas:

- I don't want to suppress the message for each occurrence.
- I specified regular expressions in `.pylintrc` to allow underscores, but then it is not possible to enforce camelCase very strictly.
- I don't want to generally disable the name checking.

Is there another way to allow such names? Something like a pylint rule "**__camelCase**" which I can apply to `class-attributes`? Or another "built-in" pythonic way?

Actually, pylint does not complain anymore after changing to `snake_case` naming convention:

```py
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, ab_ab):
      self.__ab_ab = ab_ab
```

That is a little bit weird, but that is all I wanted. So I will go with `snake_case` naming for attributes and methods.

**edit**: changing from `camelCase` to `snake_case` actually solves the problem with pylint.

Comment: There's a contradiction in your question that you're asking for a "pythonic" way to implement a non-pythonic naming convention...

Comment: @sabik: no, I'm asking about a way how to make internals private without pylint complaining about naming style. Maybe the answer is that the pythonic way is to go public, never private. I admit that this is not satisfying.

Comment: The pythonic way is to use snake_case for attribute names...

Comment: @sabik: I'm wondering how a naming style belongs strongly to a language. Nevermind, I will stick to snake_case, if it will save me some other stuff

Comment: It's part of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles); PEP8 is part of the same series of documents that is used to publish changes to the Python language itself and other core information for the past 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Underscores, except in the case of constants, are not part of camel case, so there is not a good builtin way to accomplish this. That being said, you could add to the [`attr-rgx`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/options.html#cmdoption-attr-rgx) to your `.pylintrc` with the pattern `__[a-z]+[A-Z0-9]+`, but this would be mixing naming styles, so is probably not an approach you would want to take if at all avoidable.

Ideally, for python you would be using [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) according to the official [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) preferred naming styles, for almost everything other than class names.

Keep in mind that naming conventions are just conventions and are mostly subjective, and your code will still work, it will just give of a bad "smell." In the case of libraries and apis, using unconventional naming conventions might make potential users less likely to integrate your code, so it might actually be detrimental to the success of your project.

Comment: Double underscore is for name mangling, not just a convention, so having `attr-rgx` as `(__)?[a-z]+[A-Z0-9]+` would be understandable, if odd...

Comment: I agree with @sabik that underscores at beginning are only optional. Anyway, this does not change that it is not strong enough, that's what I meant initially. Maybe my question should rather be a feature request to python ('add information-hiding to language') and to pylint ('support information-hiding'). For me this is one core feature of OOP as I want to protect that a user makes changes to intern variables which shall not be known outside, which may lead into a mess. For me this is much more important than enforcing a naming style.

Comment: Right, that's counter to the python philosophy, though. It's possible to hide information (eg. in closures), but it's not the pythonic approach. It's also unlikely to be changed in the language.

Comment: **snake_case actually solves the pylint message for attributes beginning with one or two underscores**. _I would be happy if you'd mention this right before_. My goal was not really to stick to camelCase, I just started with that and didn't know that is not "standard". I found out, when I ran pylint. Then I reconfigured it to check for camelCase. However, finally I was just annoyed why a so popular language does not well support information hiding and that the linter is complaining about name style, if trying to apply a more or less crappy way to hide information.